# Titanium Alloy - Add a status/utility bar at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Is there a *native* UI component in Titanium where you can add a utility bar at the bottom of the screen, such as the one in the iOS mail app pictured below?

The image, bar has the compose new mail button and a space for status messages. But I'd like to add a button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes titanium provided it with the name of Toolbar. Here is the documentation link for you:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.Toolbar